# clang fails with pip install on macos

Tags: python, pip, clang, macos-high-sierra

I am running `pip install scrypt==0.8.0`.
I get the following error: `error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1`.
I have xcode-select, gcc etc. installed. when i try to `cd` into that folder it doesn't exist and running `clang --version` it gives me:

```
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

full error: https://pastebin.com/JZW1jRCy

Comment: if you think that it's path that causes problem can you give me output of `which clang`? And have you tried making a soft link `ln -s /usr/bin/clang /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang`?

Comment: `/usr/bin/clang`. well... that is weird.

Comment: It's what the error message said. Why it's weired?

Comment: It's not. just went against my gut. I guess it's a different error.

Comment: full error: https://pastebin.com/JZW1jRCy

Comment: Please add it to the question and mention in topic or in tag it's issue related to macOS. It will allow easier searching for similar problem solution in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... It seems that the problem lies on Apple's side. I was able to reproduce the issue on my Macbook with High Sierra. I found [this](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2350) discussion on github regarding other cryptographic library for python and the solution they used worked for me.

```
$  env LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" pip install scrypt==0.8.0
```

Scrypt installed without any problems and I was able to import it in my interpreter:

```
$  python
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  4 2017, 06:09:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scrypt
>>> dir(scrypt)
['ERROR_MESSAGES', 'IS_PY2', 'MAXMEMFRAC_DEFAULT', 'MAXMEM_DEFAULT', 'MAXTIME_DEFAULT', 'MAXTIME_DEFAULT_ENC', 'POINTER', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__warningregistry__', '_crypto_scrypt', '_ensure_bytes', '_scrypt', '_scryptdec_buf', '_scryptenc_buf', 'c_char_p', 'c_double', 'c_int', 'c_size_t', 'c_uint32', 'c_uint64', 'cdll', 'create_string_buffer', 'decrypt', 'encrypt', 'error', 'hash', 'imp', 'os', 'pointer', 'sys']
>>>
```

I see, however, that `cryptography` library describes alternative solution [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq/). Unfortunatelly, I was unable to reproduce the issue locally after using mentioned solution so I can't say if it solves the problem. I'd suggest going through it first since it seems less intrusive.

Comment: I used the latest scrypt version instead of 0.8.0. This worked great, thanks @gonczor

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on 10.12.6 with Python 3.7.4

Comment: Also: this method worked fine when specifying either 0.8.0 and with the latest scrypt, currently 0.8.13.

Comment: Works perfect (y)